# How set parameter in SpringBoot repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this code:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select r.id, numero_registro,data_registro as dt_registro ,nr_pasta_pj as pasta, n.nome, value as objetos, (select cast ('{\"nome\" : \"' || ip.nome ||'\", \"documento\": \"' || cpf_cnpj || '\", \"qualidade\": \"'|| q.nome || '\"}' as jsonb) from indicador_pessoal ip  JOIN qualidade q ON ip.qualidade_id = q.id WHERE registro_id = r.id limit 1) as parte  FROM registro r cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(objetos) JOIN natureza n ON r.natureza_id = n.id where value @> '{id: ?1 , \"atributos\": [{\"nome\": \"?2\", \"valor\" : \"?3\"}]}'")
    List<IndicadorPessoalVO> findByObjeto ( Long id, String nome, String valor);
```

When I run this code throw the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that
>   position [1] did not exist

If I remove the parameters and change to a text works fine.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select r.id, numero_registro,data_registro as dt_registro ,nr_pasta_pj as pasta, n.nome, value as objetos, (select cast ('{\"nome\" : \"' || ip.nome ||'\", \"documento\": \"' || cpf_cnpj || '\", \"qualidade\": \"'|| q.nome || '\"}' as jsonb) from indicador_pessoal ip  JOIN qualidade q ON ip.qualidade_id = q.id WHERE registro_id = r.id limit 1) as parte  FROM registro r cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(objetos) JOIN natureza n ON r.natureza_id = n.id where value @> '{id: 1 , \"atributos\": [{\"nome\": \"nome\", \"valor\" : \"valor\"}]}'")
    List<IndicadorPessoalVO> findByObjeto ( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<IndicadorPessoalVO> findByObjeto (@Param("id") Long id,@Param("nome")String nome, @Param("valor ")String valor);
```